# logstash multiline logging with docker gelf driver

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to force logstash to not split my mulitiline logs, i'm testing it with such simple config:

```
input {
  gelf {
    port => 5055
}
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "^\s"
    what => previous
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
  }
}
```

But im getting still such error (i was trying to put it to gelf codec options too but result was that same):

> Sending Logstash's logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured
>   via log4j2.properties [2017-04-26T14:11:24,422][ERROR][logstash.agent 
>   ] Cannot load an invalid configuration {:reason=>"Expected one of #,
>   => at line 6, column 13 (byte 58) after input {\n  gelf {\n    port => 5055\n}\nfilter {\n  multiline "}

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the configuration is invalid. According to [this table](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-outputs-gelf.html) a `host` is required:

```
gelf {
    host => ...
}
```

Comment: We are talking about input plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-inputs-gelf.html